# Getting all CMAKE project outputs to end up in the same file

Tags: cmake

So we have a set of projects that create shared libraries, executables and config files that I'd like to end up all in the same directory. I can use EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH and LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH to get them all the binaries to the right place (though it would be nice  to be able to filter out just the shared libraries to this directory). However, the config files also need to end up in this directory, and I'm not sure how to make that happen.

To make the config files, we are using:

```
foreach(config_file ${${PROJECT_NAME}_CONFIG_FILES})
  ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${config_file}"
    COMMAND cmake -E copy_if_different "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${config_file}"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${config_file}"
    DEPENDS   "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${config_file}"
    )
   list(APPEND ${PROJECT_NAME}_CONFIG_FILES_DEST "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${config_file}")
endforeach(config_file)

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(${PROJECT_NAME}_configuration_files ALL DEPENDS ${${PROJECT_NAME}_CONFIG_FILES_DEST})
```

Which creates its own ends up putting the config file in the correct project directory but not the binary output directory. So if I set 'EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH=LIBARY_OUTPUT_PATH=build\bin' than i get the file layout

```
+build
-+bin
----A.exe
----B.exe
----*.lib//don't need
----*.dll
-+A
----a.xml
-+B
----b.xml
```

Which is useless. What I'd like is "PROJECT_OUTPUT_PATH", so I could send the xml files to the correct corresponding output whether or not the EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH is set. Is there a way to get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this works...it is ugly as heck but it works.

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SRC_LIST}
    ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HDR_LIST}
    ${${PROJECT_NAME}_CONFIG_FILES})
#have to move after the executable add
get_property(${PROJECT_NAME}_location TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY LOCATION)
GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(${PROJECT_NAME}_location_path ${${PROJECT_NAME}_location} PATH)

# copy all configuration files to build directory
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_CONFIG_FILES service_config.xml)
if (NOT "${${PROJECT_NAME}_location_path}" MATCHES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
foreach(config_file ${${PROJECT_NAME}_CONFIG_FILES})
  ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(OUTPUT "${${PROJECT_NAME}_location_path}/${config_file}"
    COMMAND cmake -E copy_if_different "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${config_file}"
    "${${PROJECT_NAME}_location_path}/${config_file}"
    DEPENDS   "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${config_file}"
    )
   list(APPEND ${PROJECT_NAME}_CONFIG_FILES_DEST "${${PROJECT_NAME}_location_path}/${config_file}")
endforeach(config_file)

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(${PROJECT_NAME}_configuration_files ALL DEPENDS ${${PROJECT_NAME}_CONFIG_FILES_DEST})
endif()
```

At least it works with Visual Studio and NMake.